# Why bash redirect returns error ("Directory nonexistent") under nohup

Tags: bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello" > /dev/udp/localhost/9082
```

The script executes normally under current user, however bash redirect returns an error when launched with `nohup`:

```
$ nohup ./test_redir.sh &
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[1]+  Exit 2                  nohup ./test_redir.sh
$ cat nohup.out 
./test_redir.sh: 1: ./test_redir.sh: cannot create /dev/udp/localhost/9082: Directory nonexistent
```

What can be changed to enable bash redirects with `nohup`?

Comment: This isn't specific to nohup at all. You'd have the same underlying error without it; it's only the harmless warning that's nohup-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message seems to be from `dash` <sup>(which does not support `/dev/udp/`)</sup> rather than `bash`:

```
$ bash -c 'date > /not-a-dir/file'
bash: line 1: /not-a-dir/file: No such file or directory
$ /bin/sh -c 'date > /not-a-dir/file'
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /not-a-dir/file: Directory nonexistent
$ ls -l /bin/sh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2020-11-11 11:33 /bin/sh -> dash
$
```

Double check if your script really starts with `#!/bin/bash` and has execution permission (`chmod +x`). Or try:

```
$ nohup bash /your/script.sh &
```

Comment: Indeed in this particular script the bash shebang was missing.